How can set the return-fields of GET Request URL of an API to the union of multiple paths
I am working with the Google pagespeed API and I am stuck while creating the URL fields.
The Response from this API is rather lengthy and I only care about certain paths in the api.
Right now the URL endpoint ishttps://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=https://www.apple.com/&fields=lighthouseResult%2Fcategories%2F*&prettyPrint=false&strategy=desktop&category=performance&category=best-practices&category=accessibility&category=seo.
where my return field is lighthouseResult%2Fcategories%2F*. Which returns the following response
{
    "lighthouseResult": {
        "categories": {
            "performance": {
                "id": "performance",
                "title": "Performance",
                "score": 0.93,
                "auditRefs": [
                    {
                        "id": "first-contentful-paint",
                        "weight": 10,
                        "group": "metrics",
                        "acronym": "FCP"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "largest-contentful-paint",
                        "weight": 25,
                        "group": "metrics",
                        "acronym": "LCP"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "total-blocking-time",
                        "weight": 30,
                        "group": "metrics",
                        "acronym": "TBT"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "cumulative-layout-shift",
                        "weight": 25,
                        "group": "metrics",
                        "acronym": "CLS"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "speed-index",
                        "weight": 10,
                        "group": "metrics",
                        "acronym": "SI"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "interactive",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "group": "hidden",
                        "acronym": "TTI"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "max-potential-fid",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "group": "hidden"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "first-meaningful-paint",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "group": "hidden",
                        "acronym": "FMP"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "accessibility": {
                "id": "accessibility",
                "title": "Accessibility",
                "description": "These checks highlight opportunities to [improve the accessibility of your web app](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/lighthouse/accessibility/). Automatic detection can only detect a subset of issues and does not guarantee the accessibility of your web app, so [manual testing](https://web.dev/articles/how-to-review) is also encouraged.",
                "score": 0.92,
                "manualDescription": "These items address areas which an automated testing tool cannot cover. Learn more in our guide on [conducting an accessibility review](https://web.dev/articles/how-to-review).",
                "auditRefs": [
                    {
                        "id": "accesskeys",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "group": "a11y-navigation"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "aria-allowed-attr",
                        "weight": 10,
                        "group": "a11y-aria"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "aria-allowed-role",
                        "weight": 1,
                        "group": "a11y-aria"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "aria-command-name",
                        "weight": 7,
                        "group": "a11y-aria"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "aria-conditional-attr",
                        "weight": 7,
                        "group": "a11y-aria"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "aria-deprecated-role",
                        "weight": 1,
                        "group": "a11y-aria"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "aria-dialog-name",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "group": "a11y-aria"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "aria-hidden-body",
                        "weight": 10,
                        "group": "a11y-aria"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "aria-hidden-focus",
                        "weight": 7,
                        "group": "a11y-aria"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "aria-input-field-name",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "group": "a11y-aria"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "aria-meter-name",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "group": "a11y-aria"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "aria-progressbar-name",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "group": "a11y-aria"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "aria-prohibited-attr",
                        "weight": 7,
                        "group": "a11y-aria"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "aria-required-attr",
                        "weight": 10,
                        "group": "a11y-aria"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "aria-required-children",
                        "weight": 10,
                        "group": "a11y-aria"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "aria-required-parent",
                        "weight": 10,
                        "group": "a11y-aria"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "aria-roles",
                        "weight": 7,
                        "group": "a11y-aria"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "aria-text",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "group": "a11y-aria"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "aria-toggle-field-name",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "group": "a11y-aria"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "aria-tooltip-name",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "group": "a11y-aria"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "aria-treeitem-name",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "group": "a11y-aria"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "aria-valid-attr-value",
                        "weight": 10,
                        "group": "a11y-aria"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "aria-valid-attr",
                        "weight": 10,
                        "group": "a11y-aria"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "button-name",
                        "weight": 10,
                        "group": "a11y-names-labels"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "bypass",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "group": "a11y-navigation"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "color-contrast",
                        "weight": 7,
                        "group": "a11y-color-contrast"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "definition-list",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "group": "a11y-tables-lists"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "dlitem",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "group": "a11y-tables-lists"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "document-title",
                        "weight": 7,
                        "group": "a11y-names-labels"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "duplicate-id-aria",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "group": "a11y-aria"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "form-field-multiple-labels",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "group": "a11y-names-labels"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "frame-title",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "group": "a11y-names-labels"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "heading-order",
                        "weight": 3,
                        "group": "a11y-navigation"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "html-has-lang",
                        "weight": 7,
                        "group": "a11y-language"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "html-lang-valid",
                        "weight": 7,
                        "group": "a11y-language"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "html-xml-lang-mismatch",
                        "weight": 3,
                        "group": "a11y-language"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "image-alt",
                        "weight": 10,
                        "group": "a11y-names-labels"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "image-redundant-alt",
                        "weight": 1,
                        "group": "a11y-names-labels"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "input-button-name",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "group": "a11y-names-labels"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "input-image-alt",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "group": "a11y-names-labels"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "label",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "group": "a11y-names-labels"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "link-in-text-block",
                        "weight": 7,
                        "group": "a11y-color-contrast"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "link-name",
                        "weight": 7,
                        "group": "a11y-names-labels"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "list",
                        "weight": 7,
                        "group": "a11y-tables-lists"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "listitem",
                        "weight": 7,
                        "group": "a11y-tables-lists"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "meta-refresh",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "group": "a11y-best-practices"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "meta-viewport",
                        "weight": 10,
                        "group": "a11y-best-practices"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "object-alt",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "group": "a11y-names-labels"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "select-name",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "group": "a11y-names-labels"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "skip-link",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "group": "a11y-names-labels"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "tabindex",
                        "weight": 7,
                        "group": "a11y-navigation"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "table-duplicate-name",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "group": "a11y-tables-lists"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "target-size",
                        "weight": 7,
                        "group": "a11y-best-practices"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "td-headers-attr",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "group": "a11y-tables-lists"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "th-has-data-cells",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "group": "a11y-tables-lists"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "valid-lang",
                        "weight": 7,
                        "group": "a11y-language"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "video-caption",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "group": "a11y-audio-video"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "focusable-controls",
                        "weight": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "interactive-element-affordance",
                        "weight": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "logical-tab-order",
                        "weight": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "visual-order-follows-dom",
                        "weight": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "focus-traps",
                        "weight": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "managed-focus",
                        "weight": 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            "best-practices": {
                "id": "best-practices",
                "title": "Best Practices",
                "score": 1,
                "auditRefs": [
                    {
                        "id": "is-on-https",
                        "weight": 5,
                        "group": "best-practices-trust-safety"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "redirects-http",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "group": "best-practices-trust-safety"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "geolocation-on-start",
                        "weight": 1,
                        "group": "best-practices-trust-safety"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "notification-on-start",
                        "weight": 1,
                        "group": "best-practices-trust-safety"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "csp-xss",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "group": "best-practices-trust-safety"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "paste-preventing-inputs",
                        "weight": 3,
                        "group": "best-practices-ux"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "image-aspect-ratio",
                        "weight": 1,
                        "group": "best-practices-ux"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "image-size-responsive",
                        "weight": 1,
                        "group": "best-practices-ux"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "viewport",
                        "weight": 1,
                        "group": "best-practices-ux"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "font-size",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "group": "best-practices-ux"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "doctype",
                        "weight": 1,
                        "group": "best-practices-browser-compat"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "charset",
                        "weight": 1,
                        "group": "best-practices-browser-compat"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "js-libraries",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "group": "best-practices-general"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "deprecations",
                        "weight": 5,
                        "group": "best-practices-general"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "seo": {
                "id": "seo",
                "title": "SEO",
                "description": "These checks ensure that your page is following basic search engine optimization advice. There are many additional factors Lighthouse does not score here that may affect your search ranking, including performance on [Core Web Vitals](https://web.dev/explore/vitals). [Learn more about Google Search Essentials](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769).",
                "score": 1,
                "manualDescription": "Run these additional validators on your site to check additional SEO best practices.",
                "auditRefs": [
                    {
                        "id": "is-crawlable",
                        "weight": 4.0434782608695654,
                        "group": "seo-crawl"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "document-title",
                        "weight": 1,
                        "group": "seo-content"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "meta-description",
                        "weight": 1,
                        "group": "seo-content"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "http-status-code",
                        "weight": 1,
                        "group": "seo-crawl"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "link-text",
                        "weight": 1,
                        "group": "seo-content"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "crawlable-anchors",
                        "weight": 1,
                        "group": "seo-crawl"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "robots-txt",
                        "weight": 1,
                        "group": "seo-crawl"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}

I only need the score and 4 specific auditRefs per category (For example [first-contentful-paint, largest-contentful-paint, speed-index, cumulative-layout-shift] in the performance category). How would I add these paths the return-fields expression above. I realize lighthouseResult%2Fcategories%2F*%2Fscore works for the scores but not the auditRefs.
